# refresh image src using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am creating catcha using jquery and codeigniter. My problem is during refresh of captcha image src does not refresh.

Here is the code of creating captcha

```
 <?php
```

class Get_captcha extends Controller
{

```
function Get_captcha()
{
    parent::controller();   
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');    
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));  
    $this->load->model('tools_model');                      
}

function index($random = false)
{
    $rand_string = $this->tools_model->RandomString(5);     
    $new_sess_data = array("random_number"=>$rand_string);
    $this->session->set_userdata($new_sess_data);       

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(148, 25);     
    $dir = 'fonts/';

    $num = rand(1,2);
    if($num==1)
    {
        $font = "Capture it 2.ttf"; // font style
    }
    else
    {
        $font = "Molot.otf";// font style
    }

    // random number 1 or 2
    $num2 = rand(1,2);
    if($num2==1)
    {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 113, 193, 217);// color
    }
    else
    {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 163, 197, 82);// color
    }

    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
    imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);

    imagettftext ($image, 18, 0, 38, 22, $color, $dir.$font, $this->session->userdata('random_number'));

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($image);
}
 }
```

code for html

```
 <img src="<?php echo site_url('get_captcha') ?>" alt="" id="captcha" /><a href="#" class="b" id="refresh-captcha">Refresh</a>
```

code for jquery

```
    $('#refresh-captcha').click(function(){
    $('#captcha').attr('src','<?php echo site_url('get_captcha') ?>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually changing the image.  You need to change the URL for the browser to go look for the image again.  Try changing your JS code to look like this:

```
$('#refresh-captcha').click(function(){
    var random = new Date().getTime();
    $('#captcha').attr('src','<?php echo site_url('get_captcha') ?>?random='+random);
});
```

This will force the image to be "different" each time the button is pressed.

Comment: Hi i tried your code but no image will shown. When I look at the firebug "Failed to load given URL" thanks

Comment: Well, what is the URL it tried to load?  Is it valid?  Have you tried loading it in manually?  Is site_url() outputting a valid, fully-qualified URL?